# How to Prevent Man in Middle Attack & session hijacking attack in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using IdentityServer4(.NET Core 3.1) for authentication(OIDC Protocol). but Past session id of the expired session can be used to get the authentication in the application due to this my application is vulnerable to Session Replay/Session Hjijacking/Man in Middle attack.

Kindly share some solutions for this vulnerability.

Comment: MITM protection is provided by SSL. Use TLS1.2 at least and don't disable certificate validation. Why do you assume your application is vulnerable in any way? Is this a real problem or are you trying to address issues reported by some consultant? Why would your application and Identity Server accept an *expired* session ID at all?

Comment: Thanks for your Quick response @PanagiotisKanavos. I am not assuming this issue is reported by a security consultant with proper evidance. and the server is accepting that i that is the issue. and also they are recommending "Add a new cookie that randomly changes for each login attempt. Generate
different session id before and after authentication. Also, every request after the
successful authentication should be associated with an extra session identifier
cookie which also randomly changes and expires when user logs out from the
application or closes the browser.

Comment: You're describing the default behavior except `closes the browser`. That doesn't mean the session was closed in any way. HTTP is a stateless protocol so there's no way to know if a browser is closed or not. The *client* code needs to explicitly ask to log out and the server closes the question in response. That's how all web sites work. Sessions expire to handle crashes, disconnections or users that just close the browser without logging out. Many sites have scripts that send a logout request when the browser closes but there's no guarantee the server will receive it.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about being able to use an old (but still not expired) cookie then one mitigation is to move the persistence of that session to the backend. By default the cookie is like cash, we want it to be more like a debit card.

ASP.Net Core's standard authentication cookie middleware supports implementing a backend storage mechanism for the cookie payload (i.e. the claims). This means you can invalidate sessions server-side (by deleting the record holding that data) and make any otherwise valid cookies out in the wild unusable. Check out `CookieAuthenticationOptions.SessionStore` and the `ITicketStore` interface. The end result is a cookie that just holds the session ID and expiry time which is still protected from tampering via the normal .Net Core data protection API.

If it's bearer tokens (i.e. access token JWTs issued by IdentityServer4) we're talking about then the best mitigation is to use short-lived access tokens or switch to using reference tokens and ensure they are automatically revoked as appropriate.

Backend storage doesn't solve every problem though - as @Panagiotis Kanavos points out if the user doesn't explicitly sign out then stale session could be left floating around.

Keeping cookie lifetimes short and using sliding expiration can help as it means the chance of an at-rest cookie being still usable is lower but can be a decent UX compromise as it doesn't require the user to interactively re-authentication so frequently.

Additionally, using backend storage means you can invalidate sessions based on other data changing - e.g. if the user changes their password or other security setting. You could also implement a "sign out on all devices" option by removing all session as well as refresh tokens.